# How to create an Observable<any[]>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io, rxjs

I need to get to `Observable<any[]>`. I currently have an observable that looks like this:

```
        const eventsWatcher = new Observable(observer => {
            try {
                this.socket.on('calendar-events', data => {
                    observer.next(data);
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                observer.error(err);
            }
        })
```

Basically I need to take the values from this Observable and create a new one that is an array of the values emitted by the existing observable.

I tried

```
        const arr = [];
        const eventsWatcher = new Observable(observer => {
            try {
                this.socket.on('calendar-events', data => {
                    observer.next(data);
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                observer.error(err);
            }
        }).subscribe(data => {
            arr.push(data);
        });
        return Observable.from(arr);
```

But that returns an `ArrayObservable` instead of an `Observable<any[]>`.

Sorry if I am not describing this well, but rxjs is really hard.

Comment: Do you need the new observable to emit an array for each new item? Or you just want it to emit one array, once the eventsWatcher observable is completed?

Comment: What I really need is for the new observable to emit an array every time the existing one emits a new value. The emitted array needs to contain the new value as well as all previously emitted values.

Comment: eventsWatcher emits 1,2,3. Option A: new observable emits [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]. Option B: new observable emits only [1,2,3]

Comment: Option A is what I am looking for.

Comment: Added an answer. Don't give up on Rx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *scan* operator:

```
const yourNewObservable = eventsWatcher
    .scan((acc, newItem) => acc.concat(newItem), []);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much. I actually was already looking at the scan operator, but the rxjs docs are so dense and technical, that I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: You are welcome! Sometimes it's easier to understand from examples. This site contains some examples for each operator. Try it https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html